# How to use SpringMVC @Valid to validate fields in POST and only not null fields in PUT

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, bean-validation

We are creating a RESTful API with SpringMVC and we have a /products end point where POST can be used to create a new product and PUT to update  fields. We are also using javax.validation to validate fields.

In POST works fine, but in PUT the user can pass only one field, and I can't use @Valid, so I will need to duplicate all validations made with annotation with java code for PUT.

Anyone knows how to extend the @Valid annotation and creating something like @ValidPresents or something else that solve my problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use validation groups with the Spring `org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` annotation.

> Product.java

```
class Product {
  /* Marker interface for grouping validations to be applied at the time of creating a (new) product. */
  interface ProductCreation{}
  /* Marker interface for grouping validations to be applied at the time of updating a (existing) product. */
  interface ProductUpdate{}

  @NotNull(groups = { ProductCreation.class, ProductUpdate.class })
  private String code;

  @NotNull(groups = { ProductCreation.class, ProductUpdate.class })
  private String name;

  @NotNull(groups = { ProductCreation.class, ProductUpdate.class })
  private BigDecimal price;

  @NotNull(groups = { ProductUpdate.class })
  private long quantity = 0;
}
```

> ProductController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/products")
class ProductController {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public Product create(@Validated(Product.ProductCreation.class) @RequestBody Product product) { ... }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
  public Product update(@Validated(Product.ProductUpdate.class) @RequestBody Product product) { ... }
}
```

With this code in place, `Product.code`, `Product.name` and `Product.price` will be validated at the time of creation as well as update.  `Product.quantity`, however, will be validated only at the time of update.

Answer (score 0):

What if you implements the interface Validator to customize your validation and by reflection check your constraints for any Type.

[8.2 Validation using Spring’s Validator interface](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validator)