# How can I use Spring validation in Service layer or in Controller if possible?

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring 4 and I need to validate my requests according to the type of the request.

I'm trying to validate my requests in Service layer(I don't know how can I do in controller or if I won't respect the single responsability pattern if I put this type of validation in Controllers layer).

**Why?**

I need to validate two or more types of requests like **insert a new item**, **update**, etc

Like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void insert(@RequestBody Entity entity)
```

In this case I want to use InsertEntityValidator

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void update(@RequestBody Entity entity)
```

In this case I want to use UpdateEntityValidator

**Custom validator is necessary because of Business Validation**

I don't know the ways to do that.....

Comment: See [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-validation) of the reference guide. Or just call the validator manually. (In addition read [this javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/validation/package-summary.html) on how you could do it using validation groups and JSR-303 validation).

Comment: I saw the @InitBinder but this annotation fix a validator for my controller... how can I use two validators conditionally?

Comment: Again read the documentation I pointed you at, as well as the javadoc. And as a last resort you can always manually invoke the validator...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use SpringMVC @Valid to validate fields in POST and only not null fields in PUT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741883/how-to-use-springmvc-valid-to-validate-fields-in-post-and-only-not-null-fields)